# How to insert a comma between each element in paste command in R?

Tags: r

How can I insert a comma between each element in paste command in R ?

```
paste ("X",1:5,sep="")

"X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" "X5"
```

Now I want to insert a comma between each element

```
Desired Output 

"X1","X2","X3","X4","X5"
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 15):

I think one of the two commands below should work for you:

```
> paste ("X",1:5,sep="", collapse=",")
[1] "X1,X2,X3,X4,X5"
> paste ("'","X",1:5,"'",sep="", collapse=",")
[1] "'X1','X2','X3','X4','X5'"
```

---

Update, based on comments:

There's no need to put commas "between" the vector elements.  You can use the output of your `paste` command as the `col.names` arg to `read.table`.

```
lines <-
"0 1 2 3 4
 5 6 7 8 9"

con <- textConnection(lines)
cnames <- paste("X",1:5,sep="")
x <- read.table(con, col.names=cnames)
close(con)
x
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1  0  1  2  3  4
# 2  5  6  7  8  9
```

Comment: @Joshua, the length of this vector is one, but I want it to be 5

Comment: @Tony, a comma "between" each element in a character vector doesn't make sense to me.  Why are you trying to insert a comma between each element?

Comment: @Joshua I wish to create list("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5") so that when using read.table(..., col.names= list("X1","X2","X3",X4","X5")). By default, R will assign V1 to V5, but I want to assign different names

Comment: @Tony the paste command works as a `col.names` arg.  Did you try it?